# Connect S3 via NIFI without credential

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi

Today I have a NIFI that saves data on the S3, but when changing environments and machines I put a directory with the credentials (sometimes I need to change the credential) each EC2 . I would like to know if there is a way that I can connect the S3 automatically without having to change the file with the credential at each machine change.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to set the process so that NiFi is agnostic to the credentials and just "saves data to S3", being told the credentials by the particular machine this flow is running on? Or embed the credentials in NiFi so that *no matter* which machine this flow is running on, it uses the same credentials? Both are possible.

#### Credentials provided by machine

You can populate the AWS credentials (*Access Key* and *Secret Key*) in three ways:

1. Provide a file path for the *Credentials File* processor property pointing to a file on disk which contains these credentials.
2. Populate the appropriate properties of the `PutS3Object` component using [*parameters*](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Parameters).
3. Create an `AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService` instance with those values and reference it from this processor

Whatever credentials are in the credentials file on disk, the parameter context, or the referenced controller service will be used. If the flow segment is deployed to a different NiFi instance (and the appropriate credentials file exists, or the parameters are populated, or the controller service populated [depending on the scenario]), those new values will be used.

#### Credentials embedded in NiFi flow

Either populate the AWS credentials (*Access Key* and *Secret Key*) in the appropriate properties of the `PutS3Object` component, or create an `AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService` instance with those values and reference it from this processor. If you deploy this flow to another NiFi instance, it will continue to use these same credentials.

Comment: Thank you, we used the first form, now we will start using terraform to provision the machines. With your experience, would the third option work?

Comment: Yes, you can create and populate the controller service via API just as you would with parameters or processor property direct population.